# Blank screen when packaging with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

When I package my Sencha Touch app with Phonegap builder (https://build.phonegap.com/) I don't get any errors with building.
Although, when I start the app I get a blank (white) screen and nothing happens.

What could I do wrong?

My index.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css">
<link href="resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/plugins/SliderFieldExtended.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    />
<link href="styles/OrangeTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="resources/lib/sencha-touch-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/plugins/SliderFieldExtended.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">     </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

PS. I'm using Sencha Touch 2.0.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your index file doesn't provide any clues to what is wrong. Are you performing all your DOM manipulation in another script? If not, then a blank screen is what you should expect from this file.

Comment: I've used the default Sencha Touch structure for the app

Comment: I've made a zip file of the source code. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7454879/Sencha3.zip I uploaded this zip file in the Phonegap builder and then the blank screen appears when opening on an Android device. Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for your blank screen problem that worked for me. If you upload your .zip to Phonegap Builder, the version of Phonegap is default set to the latest version, at the moment 2.1.0. In this case I also get the blank screen, but if I change the version to 2.0.0 or lower, the app works fine by me.

To change the version go to the 'Settings' tab and select the right version under 'Configuration'.

One last thing, in your `index.html` you refer to `phonegap.js`, but this file is not included in your folder.

Goodluck!

Comment: Great! It works when I choose for Phonegap 2.0.0. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution no longer works as phonegap 2.0 is not supported by the builder anymore... Any other solution ?